# Number of possible relational instances we can create having 3 drinkers and 5 beers for relation LIKES(drinker, beer)

Tags: relational-database

Here is the problem:

LIKES is a relation between drinkers and beers.  LIKES(drinker, beer)
Assume we have 3  drinkers and 5 beers.
How many possible relational instances (with no duplicates) can be formed?

Answer: 
2^15

I do not understand this answer. Could you please help me to clarify that?
Initially I though that it should be 5^3 instances. Each drinker can like all 5 beers, thus we can create relation beer/drinker... but how we get 2^15 - I cannot understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas... "instances" of what?

A table represents an application relationship. We talk about the "relationship" or "relation" LIKES or LIKES(drinker,beer) or "[drinker] likes [beer]. But "relation" is also used to mean the set of rows that "satisfy" or "participate in" or "are in" that relationship/relation or "are in relation to each other" in that way. That is why a table is called a relation--it is the (set-of-rows) relation aka table (latter meaning) corresponding to or representing a (related-in-a-certain-sense) relation aka relationship (former meaning).

(The meaning of "relation" as table is the one in "The Relational Model". The meaning of "relationship" as relationship/relation is the one in the names "Entity-Relationship Modeling" and "Object-Relational Modeling". Unfortunately certain presentations or methods or tools claiming to be "E-R M" and especially "ORM" mistakenly use the term "relationship" for what are actually foreign key constraints between tables.)

A "relationship instance" of an application relationship/relation usually means a row of values that "satisfy"/"participate"/"are in" it. Ie a row of values in the corresponding table/relation. (Eg in E-R M.) Here there are 3 * 5 of these: one of 3 drinkers paired with one of 5 beers.

But we also talk about a table/relation representing an application relationship/relation. In each application situation the sets of values that can "satisfy"/"participate"/"be in" a relationship/relation can be different. So the "instance" or "particular value" or "value for a given application situation" of a relationship/relation and its table/relation can be different per application situation. (But "instance" is a bad choice of word here because it is commonly used in the sense described earlier.)

So it sounds like "possible relation(al) instances" here means "possible table values" ("without regard to the particular application"!). Each "instance" in the row sense can be in or not in an "instance" in the relationship/table/relation sense. So for each row that can be formed using the heading of the table, it can be in the table or not. So that's 2 * ... * 2 for 3 * 5 2s, ie for 15 2s, ie 2 ^ 15 "instances".

(It's just unclear use of language. Sadly... so much confusion and so many words here just because the same words get used to mean different things.)

Answer (score 0):

There are only `15 (= 3 * 5)` possible combinations.

To visualize this draw a grid with 3 rows (use the drinkers as labels) and 5 columns (use the beers as labels). Each cell on the grid is a combination of a drinker (the row) and a beer (the column).